# In Django, how do I query that all of the related objects have the same value for a certain field?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

Let's say I have the following models in Django:

```
    class Parent(models.Model):
        pass

    class Child(models.Model):
        parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children', null=True)
        foo = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
```

How would I query the `Parent` model to find all `Parent` records where ALL of it's `children` have a value of 'ABC' for `foo`?

If I run:
`Parent.objects.filter(children__foo='ABC')`, it returns `Parent` objects where at least one of it's `children` has a value of 'ABC' for `foo`, which is not what I want. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work in the opposite way: we first filter the related `Child`ren, such that we only have children where `foo` is *not* `'ABC'`, and then we count the number of `Child`ren. If that is zero, we know that all these children have `'ABC'` (this includes `Parent`s that have no children).

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Parent.objects.annotate(
    nabc=Count('children', filter=~Q(children__foo='ABC'))
).filter(
    nabc=0
)
```

This will produce a query that looks like:

```
SELECT parent.*,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN NOT (child.foo = ABC AND child.foo IS NOT NULL)
             THEN child.id ELSE NULL END) AS nabc
FROM parent LEFT OUTER JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
GROUP BY parent.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN NOT (child.foo = ABC AND child.foo IS NOT NULL)
             THEN child.id ELSE NULL END) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! This did it. I found a solution by running 2 queries, but this I like this better. Here's what I came up with: `children = Child.objects.exclude(foo='ABC').order_by('parent_id').distinct().values_list('parent_id', flat=True)
Parent.filter(~Q(id__in=list(children)))`